# How can I repair a broken lens?

Tags: lens, canon, troubleshooting, repair

The lens is a Canon EF-S 18-55mm.

I recently dropped my camera from the tripod falling over while I was recording, now the camera won't AF and MF is very hard.  It gets stuck easily when I try to MF it, and doesn't focus properly.  I can zoom in or out, that is completely stuck.  When I move the lens around I can hear a rolling noise inside it, like a marble.  I had a fisheye conversion lens on it which I *thought* took the impact due to the paint ear on the edge it fell.  I've read it costs about $200-$300 to fix this, and would prefer to fix it on my own.  Does anyone know what the issue is so I can fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You're between a rock and a hard place: professional repairs are expensive, but a new lens is also. There are videos showing [the teardown of the Canon EF-S 18-55mm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9ttsc6Yl4w), [and another](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGsXxDiH17M), and you can find more. However, this work is best done in clean-room, or at least well filtered area, and the *slightest* mistake can cause more damage.

As was stated, a new lens is [~US$200](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000V5K3FG) or less, so professional repair does not seem cost-effective. If the lens is totally inoperative now, and you want to do this for a learning experience, it seems you have little to lose... and there is a small chance the lens can be made partially useful (e.g. but with autofocus broken), or used for parts.

Answer (score 0):

Fixation, a UK authorised Canon Service Centre, don't offer a repair on the EF-S 18-55 - possibly because it's never economically viable as it's a cheap(ish) lens.